# Conan: Unable to build libvpx msvc compiler

Tags: c++, windows, conan

I am trying to use libvpx as one of my dependencies of a C++ project using conan.

Using Linux, everything works fine with my current `conanfile.txt`.

Under Windows, I get an error, which I tracked down to the installation of libvpx, which I then tried to run separately with my current compiler configuration:

When I try to execute

```
conan install "libvpx/1.11.0@" --build missing --env CC="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/
bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" --env CXX="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" --settings arch=x86_64 --settings build_type=Debug --settings compiler="Visual Studio" --settings compiler.version=16 --settings compiler.runtime=MDd --settings compiler.cppstd=20
```

I get

```
ERROR: libvpx/1.11.0: Error in build() method, line 171
        autotools = self._configure_autotools()
while calling '_configure_autotools', line 165
        autotools.configure(args=args, configure_dir=self._source_subfolder, host=False, build=False, target=False)
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing /c/users/juliu/.conan/data/libvpx/1.11.0/_/_/build/92e954da5bf61eb674376096f10cb67d2ac6fffa/source_subfolder/configure --prefix=/c/users/juliu/.conan/data/libv
px/1.11.0/_/_/package/92e954da5bf61eb674376096f10cb67d2ac6fffa --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --disable-tools --disable-docs --enable-vp9-highbitdepth --as=yasm --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-debug --target=x86_64-win64-vs16 --disable-avx --disable-avx2 --disable-avx512
```

When I then look into the build directory's config.log file,  I see the following log output:

```
# /c/users/juliu/.conan/data/libvpx/1.11.0/_/_/build/92e954da5bf61eb674376096f10cb67d2ac6fffa/source_subfolder/configure --prefix=/c/users/juliu/.conan/data/libvpx/1.11.0/_/_/package/92e954da5bf61eb674376096f10cb67d2ac6fffa --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --disable-tools --disable-docs --enable-vp9-highbitdepth --as=yasm --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-debug --target=x86_64-win64-vs16 --disable-avx --disable-avx2 --disable-avx512
  enabling vp8_encoder
  enabling vp8_decoder
  enabling vp9_encoder
  enabling vp9_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86_64-win64-vs16'
  enabling x86_64
check_cpp
BEGIN /tmp/vpx-conf-1948-24757.c
     1  #if !defined(__ILP32__) || !defined(__x86_64__)
     2  #error "not x32"
     3  #endif
END /tmp/vpx-conf-1948-24757.c
/c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.29.30133/bin/hostx64/x64/cl.exe -E -o /tmp/vpx-conf-1948-24757.o /tmp/vpx-conf-1948-24757.c
/c/users/juliu/.conan/data/libvpx/1.11.0/_/_/build/92e954da5bf61eb674376096f10cb67d2ac6fffa/source_subfolder/build/make/configure.sh: line 295: /c/program: No such file or directory
```

And some other output, also indicating that the directory /c/program cannot be found.

I tried running conan with different compilers, and received different errors. Did I configure something incorrectly?

Conan version 1.57.0

*edit*: I saw that installing using C++14 standard works, because then it just downloads a pre-build binary, but it does not work for c++ >= 17

**edit2**: I edited the profile

```
[settings]
os=Windows
os_build=Windows
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler="Visual Studio"
compiler.version=16
compiler.cppstd=20
#compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
build_type=Release
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CXX="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
CC="C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
```

and executed

```
 conan install "libvpx/1.11.0@" --build missing
```

but I still encounter an error message:

```
Unable to invoke compiler: /c/program files/microsoft visual studio/2022/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.29.30133/bin/hostx64/x64/cl.exe 

Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.log) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.
libvpx/1.11.0:
```

Comment: Why do you need to set your compiler by environment variables? You should use your Conan profile instead, to choose which Visual Studio version you want, then, Conan client will run the configuration for you. It seems like you are trying to skip the profile and forcing another compiler version.

Comment: @uilianries thanks, I will try doing so, and adapt the default profile to use the compiler I would like to use. I used env variables above, because I have got a conan integration into CMake, and that was the command that the integration executes by default when loading the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: With the new integrations that are 2.0-ready, it is also possible to configurate compilers with ``tools.build:compiler_executables`` new ``conf``, and that will be listened by ``CMakeToolchain``, ``MesonToolchain``, ``AutotoolsToolchain``, new generators. But if ``libvpx`` is from ConanCenter, it might not have been updated yet.

Comment: Indeed there are few issues listed in ConanCenterIndex related to libvpx: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc+libvpx
I would recommend you opening a new issue there, so the community can track one more behavior to be fixed. Thank you for your extra details.

Comment: Autotools don't support CC & CXX with paths containing spaces (libvpx has a custom configure script, but it has probably the same issues than configure scripts generated by autotools). There is a PR in conan proposing a workaround on Windows (sanitizing CC & CXX with a conversion to short names): https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/12194 . But it's for the new `AutotoolsToolchain` generator, not legacy `AutotoolsBuildEnvironment` build helper `libvpx` recipe is still using. And I don't even know if this PR will be merged.